# How to draw hypergraphs?

Tags: drawing, draw, dot

I've searched for a long time a program that could draw hypergraphs, I've onl found the (marvelous) dot program on linux that can draw graphs. Anyone knows an equvalent for hypergraphs?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [java implementation on sourceforge](http://hypergraph.sourceforge.net/) that works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather from the definition of hypergraphs in wikipedia, hypergraphs are already included in the dot program. Try subgraphs!